# Twitter & Python: Struggling to understand my 'list index out of range' issue here

Tags: python, list, twitter

I am working on a beginners twitter-python project and I'm following the below page:

https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/earth-analytics-python/using-apis-natural-language-processing-twitter/calculate-tweet-word-bigrams-networks-in-python/

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import itertools
import collections

import tweepy as tw
import nltk
from nltk import bigrams
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re
import networkx as nx

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

sns.set(font_scale = 1.5)
sns.set_style('whitegrid')

consumer_key = 'xxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxx'
access_token = 'xxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxx'

auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit = True)

search_term = 'Ocado -filter:retweets'

tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
                  q = search_term,
                  lang = 'en',
                  since = '2020-03-01').items(100)

def remove_url(txt):
    """Replace URLs found in a text string with nothing
    (i.e. it will remove the URL from the string).

    Parameters
    ----------
    txt: a string
         A text string that you want to parse and remove urls.

    Returns
    -------
    The same txt string with URLs removed.
    """

    return " ".join(re.sub("([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", "", txt).split())

# Remove URLs
tweets_no_urls = [remove_url(tweet.text) for tweet in tweets]

# Create a sublist of lower case words for each tweet
words_in_tweet = [tweet.lower().split() for tweet in tweets_no_urls]

# Download stopwords
nltk.download('stopwords')
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

# Remove stop words from each tweet list of words
tweets_nsw = [[word for word in tweet_words if not word in stop_words]
              for tweet_words in words_in_tweet]

# Remove collection words
collection_words = ['ocado', 'delivery', 'change']

tweets_nsw_nc = [[w for w in word if not w in collection_words]
                 for word in tweets_nsw]

#Create a list of lists containing bigrams in tweets
terms_bigram = [list(bigrams(tweet)) for tweet in tweets_nsw_nc]

#View bigrams from the first tweet
terms_bigram[0]
```

The problem occurs with Bigrams:

The error I see:

*IndexError Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      3 
      4 #View bigrams from the first tweet
----> 5 terms_bigram[0]

IndexError: list index out of range*

I cannot understand this. Can someone help me see why the list index is out of range when I try to do the terms_bigrams?

Comment: Have you checked that the list `terms_bigram` is not empty? You should check your assignments at each step to verify that your outputs are what you think they are

Comment: Yeah the list in the assignment returns a list of bigrams - I followed it step by step from the link I posted in my post. Any idea where in my code the list becomes empty?

Comment: We have no way of knowing that, since we can't access the data the same way you would. You need to check the output at each step, and figure out why your list is empty